# Grammaticality of "Where go the hours"

Tags: word-order, writing-style

In a recent [comic](https://poorlydrawnlines.com/?p=8368) by Poorly Drawn Lines, I came across the following sentences :

> Where go the hours? Where go the days?

> Son of a gun, where **do** go they?

Though the last sentence is clearly jokingly incorrect, I initially thought the first ones were a literary, poetic or archaic but correct formulation. However I looked it up and I couldn't find anything on this type of sentence, so I'm not sure.

Can this construction be found elsewhere? And what effect does this word order produce for a native speaker? (*Failed attempt at profound poetry, childish and blatant grammatical error, something else?*)

Comment: It's a surprise reversal for effect. Something wicked this way comes, *if you shall be so audacious as to wish to sound bewitching* in Macbeth. Notable for the ages, right? Ask not what order is wrong, ask what you can do to avoid sounding like some scriptwriter of old.

Comment: It seems to be a valid but archaic word order. From the 1687 play *The Rehearsal*: ["Well, and where lies the Jest of that?"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Rehearsal/y_VbAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22where+lies+the%22&pg=PA32&printsec=frontcover) As a native speaker, I assumed it was a fairly common archaic word order, but I didn't find it in Shakespeare, so it must have been less common that I thought.

Comment: @PeterShor Shakespeare used "*whither* goeth/st." as **go** is a verb of motion. A Winter's Tale -  MOPSA.  *"Thou hast sworn it more to me. Then whither goest? Say, whither?"*

Comment: @YosefBaskin neat!

Comment: @Greybeard In fact, especially with "whither," even the verb can often be deleted: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22whither+the%22&sxsrf=APq-WBsbiGgym9EK16W6HHWhETSpuTiMZw:1643907435834&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj85oW2gOT1AhVCVd8KHRg0C8YQ_AUoAXoECAEQCw&biw=2560&bih=1304&dpr=2

Comment: @AndyBonner: I'd forgotten that! That construction always makes me laugh.

Comment: Do-support (or another auxiliary, 'Where are ...' / ''What have ...') is necessary in the modern framing of interrogatives headed by a wh-word. In archaic language, inversion was used.

Answer (score 1):

> Where go the hours? Where go the days?

This is known as adverb fronting inversion.

[Random Idea English](https://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2014/09/exploring-inversion-and-fronting.html?m=1) has a good explanation:

> Inversion and fronting
>
> Inversion is often used in connection with fronting. Sometimes fronting involves inversion, often it doesn't. Sometimes that inversion is obligatory, sometimes it isn't.
>
> •  Fronting of a negative adverb, with obligatory inversion.
> He had never seen such a wonderful sunset. (standard word order)
> Never had he seen such a wonderful sunset. (fronted with inversion)
>
> •  Fronting of a prepositional phrase, with optional inversion
> A large dog lay in front of the fireplace. (standard word order)
> In front of the fireplace, lay a large dog. (fronted with inversion)
> In front of the fireplace, a large dog was chewing a bone. (fronted, no inversion)

As you can imagine, in current Modern English, these negative and locative phrases are the most likely to cause inversion.

The commonest is of the type: "There(adv.) is a cat(subject)."

But we also have "so do I"

Earlier, many free-modifier phrases and clauses - and also adjectival phrases and clauses - commonly caused inversion:

"Long was the road, but dearly did he love her."

Comment: Not the answer. This is the modern use of do-support for wh-questions.